# CameraCaptureUI in some container

Tags: c#, camera, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I like to create screen in my windows store application with default CameraCaptureUI. CameraCaptureUI can be started with following code

```
var cameraUI = new CameraCaptureUI();
var capturedMedia = await cameraUI.CaptureFileAsync(CameraCaptureUIMode.Photo);
```

This code open camera on whole sceen. What I need is running camera inside my winstore application e.g. in some container and add some more controls to the same screen.

Do you have any clue if it is possible? If yes, what is best way how to do this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add capabilities "Microphone" and "Webcam".

[image]

2) Define `CaptureElement` in the view.

```
 <CaptureElement Name="captureElement"/>
```

3) Create field in your class `MediaCapture`.

```
private readonly MediaCapture _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
```

4) Create method that fill `CaputreElement` with live content from camera.

```
async Task ShowPreview()
{
    try
    {
        await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
        captureElement.Source = _mediaCapture;
        await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // exception handling ...            
    }
}
```

5) Invoke `ShowPreview` method:

```
ShowPreview();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MediaCapture control to create a custom photo UI within your app. The CameraCaptureUI is not customizable. It is intended to be an easy way to get a default UI.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx